# How to use redirects on Nodes that are only used to populate block Views

Tags: nodes, redirection

I have a custom content type that is really only used to populate a views banner, so I don't want that node to ever be browsed to or indexed.

I'm thinking this is a redirect kind of scenario, but I don't know exactly what that should mean. I'm using Clean URLS and [Path Auto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)

Would something like [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) be what I need or is there something else I should use?

Thinking ahead, there are other content type nodes that will have the same requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module for this.

> Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.
>   Perhaps you have a content type that never should be displayed on its own page, like an image content type that's displayed in a carousel. Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own page, through node/xxx.
>
> **Options**
>
> This works by providing multiple options to control what should happen when the entity is being viewed at its own page. You have the ability to
>
> Deliver an access denied page.
>
> Deliver a page not found page.
>
> Issue a page redirect to any path or external url.
>
> Or simply display the entity (regular behavior).
>
> This is configurable per bundle and per entity. There is also a permission that lets certain roles override Rabbit Hole completely.